# Reading deadlettered messages from service bus queue

Tags: java, azure-servicebus-queues, dead-letter, brokeredmessage

I would like to know if it's possible to read deadlettered messages from an azure service bus queue in JAVA.

I found the following example https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Brokered-Messaging-Dead-22536dd8/sourcecode?fileId=123792&pathId=497121593 
However, I haven't been able to translate the code to JAVA.

I also found https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/tree/master/microsoft-azure-storage/src/com/microsoft/azure/storage 
But there does not seem to be anything about deadlettering in there at all.

I also found several blogs (i'm not allowed to put more links so I don't know if I should anyway without proper tags). But they all do not describe how to read deadlettered messages in JAVA.

Much thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know it's an old thread but for next lost soul looking for a solution...

I've been digging in the .NET SDK source and found that it's actually just a simple HTTP call to "/$DeadLetterQueue", i.e.:

```
https://mynamespace.servicebus.windows.net/myqueuename/$DeadLetterQueue/messages/head

// Peek-Lock Message from DLQ
curl -X POST -H "authorization: insertSASHere" "https://mynamespace.servicebus.windows.net/myqueuename/%24DeadLetterQueue/messages/head"
```

So using the Java SDK all you need to read messages from a Dead Letter Queue is:

```
service.receiveQueueMessage(queueName + "/$DeadLetterQueue", opts);
```

Here's a very basic but concrete example (destructive read):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ServiceException {

    String namespace        = "namespace";
    String sharedKeyName    = "keyName";
    String sharedSecretKey  = "secretKey";
    String queueName        = "queueName";      
    
    // Azure Service Bus Service
    Configuration config = ServiceBusConfiguration.configureWithSASAuthentication(namespace, sharedKeyName, sharedSecretKey, ".servicebus.windows.net");
    ServiceBusContract service = ServiceBusService.create(config);

    // Receive and Delete Messages from DLQ
    ReceiveMessageOptions opts = ReceiveMessageOptions.DEFAULT;
    opts.setReceiveMode(ReceiveMode.RECEIVE_AND_DELETE);

    while (true) {
        // To get messages from the DLQ we just need the "$DeadLetterQueue" URI
        ReceiveQueueMessageResult resultQM = service.receiveQueueMessage(queueName + "/$DeadLetterQueue", opts);
        BrokeredMessage message = resultQM.getValue();
        if (message != null && message.getMessageId() != null) {
            System.out.println("MessageID: " + message.getMessageId());
        } else {
            System.out.println("No more messages.");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the Java aspect, but receiving dead-lettered messages is exactly the same mechanics as reading active message, but the queue name is different.

Using the API you can call QueueClient.FormatDeadLetterPath("NormalQueuePath") to get the deadletter path name.  You can then use this in a call to QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(...) to get a client you can receive deadlettered messages from.